# « Il nous a permis de se rendre compte » ou « il nous a permis de nous rendre compte » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Laquelle de ces deux tournures est correcte et pourquoi ?

> A) Ce projet nous a permis de **se** rendre compte que...
>
> B) Ce projet nous a permis de **nous** rendre compte que...

Comment: *Ce projet permet de se rendre compte que...* / *Ce projet lui permet de se rendre compte que...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La seconde tournure est correcte :

> *Ce projet nous a permis de nous rendre compte que...*

Par défaut, on utilise le pronom réfléchi *soi* (ou *se* dans sa forme conjointe) [dans les situations suivantes](https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-reflechis) :

- Le sujet est indéfini ou neutre.

> *Il est important de prendre du temps pour **soi**.*

- Avec *on, chacun, tout le monde, personne, celui qui*.

> *Personne ne **se** prend au sérieux ici !*

Ici, nous ne sommes dans aucun des deux cas. Le sujet est clairement défini, il s'agit du premier *nous*.

**EDIT**: suite à la réponse de Grandtout, je souhaite apporter un peu de nuance à cette réponse. Comme il l'a indiqué, la formulation "nous a permis de se rendre compte" est parfois utilisée, en partant du principe que le sujet est le pronom *on*.

Answer (score 2):

La suite de mots "nous a permis de se rendre compte" donne sur google 67 résultats, alors que "nous a permis de nous rendre compte" en donne 296.  Si la première est incorrecte, elle ne l'est certainement pas au même titre que "m'a permis de se rendre compte", par exemple, qui donne deux résultats qu'on peut rejeter comme aberrants.  C'est que "nous" peut être considéré comme la forme objet du pronom "on", de même que "me" est celle de "je".

Je me suis rendu compte grâce à ce projet que… —  Ce projet m'a permis de me rendre compte que...

On s'est rendu compte grâce à ce projet que… — Ce projet nous a permis de se rendre compte que...

Peut-on dire que "nous a permis de se rendre compte que…" est incorrect ?   Certainement d'un point de vue prescriptif, et, dans une moindre mesure, descriptif puisque ce tour est attesté à l'écrit de manière non négligeable.  Je pense, c'est une intuition qu'il faudrait vérifier, qu'il est utilisé plus largement dans le français parlé familier où "nous" a cédé la place à "on".

Comment: Pédant est un bien grand mot, mais c'est un point de vue très intéressant ! Pour ma part, à partir du moment où "on" n'a pas de pronom personnel, il me semble plus logique que le sujet soit toujours considéré comme "nous" dans un contexte comme celui de cette phrase. En revanche, je suis de ceux qui croient que l'usage fait le langage, et je ne peux pas dire que l'usage avec "se" soit incorrect à partir du moment où il provient d'un raisonnement logique et est très répandu. Je vais donc éditer ma réponse pour nuancer un peu mon propos. Merci pour cette réponse !

Comment: @Reyedy  J'ai supprimé "pédant" qui peut être pris en mauvaise part.

Comment: Ton analyse est faussée par une mauvaise interprétation des chiffres de Google. Ce moteur de recherche ne trouve pas 700000 résultats pour la forme avec *se* et 315000 pour la forme avec *nous*. Les valeurs affichées pour une recherche libre sont une estimation ignorant l'ordre des mots. Quand on demande les chaînes précises, Google retourne 67 résultats avec *se* et 296 avec *nous*. Pour les documents imprimés, Google Books ne trouve **aucune** occurrence de *nous a permis de se* et de très nombreux *nous a permis de nous* qui est donc bien la seule forme acceptable par les relecteurs.

Comment: @jlliagre  merci pour ces infos.  J'avais fait une recherche en entourant la phrase de guillemets pourtant.  Cela n'invalide pas foncièrement mon analyse, je crois, mais, en tous cas, la nuance.

Comment: Suite à ces nouvelles informations, j'ai de nouveau édité ma réponse pour nuancer la nuance !

Comment: Le rapport 67 / 296 n'est pas vraiment significatif non plus. Malgré sa puissance de calcul, Google n'indexe pas toutes les suites de mots possibles sur l'ensemble des centaines de milliards de pages analysées. Les totaux fournis ne sont que des approximations statistiques. Au delà de 200 ou 300 liens retournés, la recherche n'est pas forcément exhaustive, et Google refuse de donner plus de 1000 documents pour une recherche donnée. Le seul outil permettant d'obtenir des chiffres assez fiables pour des séquences contenant jusqu'à cinq mots est Google books.

Comment: Cela-dit, je suis d'accord pour reconnaître que *ça nous a permis de se lever à l'heure* peut s'entendre contrairement à *ça m'a permis de se lever à l'heure*.